# How to prove the existence of a global smooth vector field on Mobius strip that is no where $0$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

This question was asked in my exercise of differential geometry and I am not able to prove what I was asked.

Question: Denote by Mob, the Mobius "strip" which is vector bundle over $S^{1}$ with typical fiber $\mathbb{R}$. Then show that there exists a global smooth vector field on Mob that is nowhere $0$.

Unfortunately, I am not able to construct such a vector field. Can you please give some leads?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you construct a smooth nonvanishing vector field on $S^1$?

Comment: @IDC I have proved that such a non vanishing smooth vector field exists on $S^{1}$ in another exercise.

Comment: Good! Now think about how you can lift it to the Mobius strip.

Comment: @IDC I am not sure how can I lift it to Mobius strip. Can you please write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a differential geometer, and I am sure there are much more elegant ways to write this down. You should try to find one such way yourself.

Write the Möbius strip $M$ as the strip $I\times \mathbb{R}$, $I=[0,1]$ with the points $(0,x)$ and $(1,-x)$ glued together. Then giving a nonvanishing vector field on $M$ is equivalent to just giving a smooth (including being smooth at the glued points) function $(\xi,\eta):I\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\xi(0,x)=\xi(1,-x),\ \eta(0,x)=-\xi(1,-x).$ Here $\xi$ and $\eta$ correspond to the horizontal and vertical direction.

And now you can just take your nonvanishing vector field on a circle to get $\xi$ and take $\eta$ as identically zero.

The geometric picture is this: you just take a vector field orthogonal to the fibers $\mathbb{R}$ of the strip.

Comment: I don't think your claim of equivalence is quite accurate. You also need to impose symmetry conditions on all derivatives of $\xi$ and $\eta$, otherwise the induced map on $M$ has no reason to be smooth.

Comment: @Thorgott Of course, I implicitly assumed that everything that needs to be smooth.